# New line in MS-DOS Assembly?

Tags: assembly, dos

I'm very new to Assembly in MS-DOS, and I can't figure out how the new line function works at all. Here is what I have:

```
org 0100h

myloop:
mov cx, 0005h

mov ah,09h
mov dx,hello
int 21h

dec cx
jnz myloop

mov ax, 4c00h
int 21h

hello: db 'Hello World!',0ah,0dh,'My Name',24h
```

Any help would be appreciated, all I get when I execute is `Hello World!`, when I want to get this:

```
Hello World!

My Name
```

Comment: DOS uses `CR`, `LF` that is `0dh`, `0ah` but you have it reversed. It may or may not matter, though. Also, you loop back to `myloop` which reloads `cx` so you get an endless loop. Finally, don't bother with DOS, it's obsolete and a waste of time.

Comment: If you want an extra line feed, use hello: db 'Hello World!',0dh,0ah,0ah,'My Name',24h

Comment: As long we can boot DOS it is not obsolete. And it is not a waste of time if we can learn the first steps of x86 assembly. A lot of x64 starts within the 16 bit realmode and with booting DOS it is also possible to switch into the 64 bit long mode. Starting with DOS for to learn the first steps of x86 assemble is not a bad choice. Similar there is a little difference for a new pilot for to learn flying a space rocket starting from the space station, or learning to start a small aeroplane without a jet engine from the runway of an airport.

Comment: The segment awareness that working in DOS assembly instills is utterly pointless in protected mode.

Comment: But with using DOS and within the 16 bit realmode we can use many Bios routines, example for to switch into a true color video mode for to fit the native widescreen resolution of modern digital monitors without to need a driver. And after setting the video mode we can switch into the protected mode, example for to address and for using the linear framebuffer(LFB). So DOS is not totally in opposition with the protected mode, it is more an other startpoint for to learn of using the protected mode from scratch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've always used 13,10 for newlines...  I don't think having it backwards would have much of an effect though. Also...  It would appear that you are in an infinite loop of printing? Setting CX to 5, printing, then decrementing it, then jumping right before the line that you set it to 5...  Anyways, you can always try using `LEA DX, hello` (I'm a little rusty but that's what I recall always using).

-Kyle

Comment: Assuming this is NASM syntax, `mov dx, hello` has the same result as `lea dx, [hello]`, but is more efficient and smaller machine-code size.  You're apparently remembering MASM/TASM syntax, where the equivalent mov would be `mov dx, OFFSET hello`.  Also, probably a good idea to have a CR LF after the 2nd line in case the prompt overwrites it after program exit.